# php email: multiple precipitants using checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, email

I am currently trying to create a form so people can select a number of check boxes with each one corresponding to a person and email address. They can then fill out the rest of the form and send the email to everyone they selected. This is the code I have so far and it does not seem to be working. Any clues and ideas would be great

Form

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post"  name="contact_form">
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name1" id="thing"/><label for="thing" class="name1"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name2" id="thing2"/><label for="thing2" class="name2"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name3" id="thing3"/><label for="thing3" class="name3"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name4" id="thing4"/><label for="thing4" class="name4"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name5" id="thing5"/><label for="thing5" class="name5"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name6" id="thing6"/><label for="thing6" class="name6"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name7" id="thing7"/><label for="thing7" class="name7"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name8" id="thing8"/><label for="thing8" class="name8"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="emails" value="name9" id="thing9"/><label for="thing9" class="name9"></label>
<div class="title_bar">Name</div>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Urbanist" required/>
<div class="title_bar">Email</div>
<input type="email" name="from_email" placeholder="john_urbanist@example.com" required/>
<div class="title_bar" style="height:202px;">Additional Comments</div><textarea name="additional" maxlength="300" required></textarea>
<div style="clear:both;display:block;"></div>
<button class="buttonsend submit" type="submit">Send Letter</button>
</form>
```

Mail.php

```
$mails = array(
'email@domain.com' => 'name1',
'email2@domain.com' => 'name2',
'email3@domain.com' => 'name3',
'email4@domain.com' => 'name4',
'email5@domain.com' => 'name5',
'email6@domain.com' => 'name6',
'email7@domain.com' => 'name7',
'email8@domain.com' => 'name8',
'email9@domain.com' => 'name9'
);
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$subject = 'Hello';
$additional = $_REQUEST["additional"];
$from_email = $_REQUEST["from_email"];
$headers = "From: ".$from_email."\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: php";

foreach ($_POST['emails'] as $value) {
if (in_array($value, $mails)) {
$addrs = array_keys($mails, $value);

foreach ($addrs as $addr) {
if (mail($addr, $subject, $additional, $headers)) {
echo("Message sent!");
} else {
echo("Message delivery failed...");
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: nothing its just not sending anything

Comment: Did you try the php mailer class? http://phpmailer.worxware.com/
The difficulty are to construct the headers for all clients

Comment: I have similar forms on my website (without checkboxes) that work fine. I think it is something to do with they checkbox array but i just can't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP-mailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ you have a lot of options to set like

```
    $userMail = new phpmailer;
    $userMail->IsMail();
    $userMail->IsHTML(true);
    $userMail->Priority = 3;
    $userMail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    //...
    $userMail->From = 'm2@me.com';
    $userMail->FromName = SITE_OWNERS;

    foreach($whatever as $key => $what) {
        $userMail->AddAddress($key, $what);
    }
    //etc...
    $userMail->WordWrap = 50;
    //etc...
```

And at the end

```
if($userMail->Send()){
    //do yes
} else {
    //do no
}
```

AND what [rossco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2485467/rossco) said!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [] to the name of the checkboxes for it to be understood as an array.

Form

```
 <form action="mail.php" method="post"  name="contact_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name1" id="thing"/><label for="thing" class="name1"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name2" id="thing2"/><label for="thing2" class="name2"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name3" id="thing3"/><label for="thing3" class="name3"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name4" id="thing4"/><label for="thing4" class="name4"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name5" id="thing5"/><label for="thing5" class="name5"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name6" id="thing6"/><label for="thing6" class="name6"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name7" id="thing7"/><label for="thing7" class="name7"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name8" id="thing8"/><label for="thing8" class="name8"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="name9" id="thing9"/><label for="thing9" class="name9"></label>
    <div class="title_bar">Name</div>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Urbanist" required/>
    <div class="title_bar">Email</div>
    <input type="email" name="from_email" placeholder="john_urbanist@example.com" required/>
    <div class="title_bar" style="height:202px;">Additional Comments</div><textarea name="additional" maxlength="300" required></textarea>
    <div style="clear:both;display:block;"></div>
    <button class="buttonsend submit" type="submit">Send Letter</button>
    </form>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
    //print_r($_POST['emails']);
    $mails = array(
    'email@domain.com' => 'name1',
    'email2@domain.com' => 'name2',
    'email3@domain.com' => 'name3',
    'email4@domain.com' => 'name4',
    'email5@domain.com' => 'name5',
    'email6@domain.com' => 'name6',
    'email7@domain.com' => 'name7',
    'email8@domain.com' => 'name8',
    'email9@domain.com' => 'name9'
    );
    $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
    $subject = 'Hello';
    $additional = $_REQUEST["additional"];
    $from_email = $_REQUEST["from_email"];
    $headers = "From: ".$from_email."\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: php";

    foreach ($_POST['emails'] as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $mails)) {
    $addrs = array_keys($mails, $value);

    foreach ($addrs as $addr) {
    if (mail($addr, $subject, $additional, $headers)) {
    echo("Message sent!");
    } else {
    echo("Message delivery failed...");
    }
    }
    }
    } ?>
```

Comment: this is working for some email but not for others? do you know why this would be?

Comment: when I run it with all checkboxes selected all of the resulting mail functions run successfully.